# Extract symbol table from ELF into a .o

Tags: c, llvm, symbols, bare-metal

I'm writing a bare metal application for a device connected over serial. The device already has some base code on it (maybe considered an OS), but I want to be able to cross-compile code on my computer, send the machine code over serial, and have the device load the machine code into memory and run it. I don't have any real need for security, so both the base code and the machine code sent over serial are run in supervisor mode (this is an ARM device) and has access to the full physical memory with no paging. All the code in question is written in C (and a bit of assembly that can be ignored).

My only issue is that I want the newly compiled machine code to be able to call subroutines defined in the base code. For example, the base code has a `printf` function that writes to a display and I want to be able to call that `printf` function from the code I send over serial. I figured I may be able to extract that `printf` function out of the base code and into a reusable library, however, the device has limited memory so I don't want to link it statically and I think a dynamic linker is overkill.

My current idea is to let the code being sent over serial be compiled with the base code's symbols. Both end up being run on the same machine so there shouldn't be any problem. The current build process cross-compiles my C code with Clang to an ELF, then uses `objcopy code.elf -O binary code.img` to extract the machine code. The only problem is that the code compiled to be sent over serial has no access to the symbol for the base code. I somehow need to extract the symbol table from `base.elf` and pass it while linking `serial_code.o`.

How can I do this? Preferably with LLVM utilities.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extract your symbol table.  You need to link your code with the symbols of the code already used in the base code.  You can link your base code (the code that has no unsatisfied references) normally, and then link your module as a shared object (a dynamically linked module) and all the linking will be done at shared object load.

That is the general way to do it.  If you try to do it yourself, by exploring the base executable to locate the symbols and resolving the references at runtime, you will be doing extactly what the dynamic linker is doing at link time, so your code will grow (but not optimized as the dynamic linker is) to the size it actually has.  You are reinventing the wheel and you will probably have a long debugging period before you get something deliverable.

I'd propose you to read full documentation on how the linker `ld` works (the way of writing linker scripts) as it offers far more possibilities than the ones I have described above.

Another possibility is to make a table of entry points to the functions and initialize it in some global variable.  You have only to access the pointers to the functions you will be offered by the base software, so you can access the entry points from the pointers stored in the global variable.

```
/* this to be defined in a global .h file */
struct GLOBAL_ENTRY_POINTS {
     void function_a(int param_1, double param_2);
     ...
};

/* global variable defined in a compilation unit */
struct GLOBAL_ENTRY_POINTS global_entry_points = {  .function_a = function_a_impl, ... };
```

Then, in your code you can be given by some external means the position of that global variable and call

```
    extern struct GLOBAL_ENTRY_POINTS global_entry_points;

    global_entry_points.function_a(3, 3.141592654);
```

when your code is loaded into memory.

This approach doesn't require any calculations, as the addresses of the main code have been allocated when the linker was called. And are accessible once you have the address of that global variable.  (All this can be determined at build time, statically, so you don't need to do anything at runtime).

Comment: Thanks Jens for the typo corrections!!!

Comment: `extern` in structure definition makes no sense as type definitions have no linkage. Did you mean to have it on `global_entry_points` definition?

Comment: @user694733, thanks, you're right.... It was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get a solution with `objcopy` working, however all this approach needs is `readelf` and some scripting language (I used Python). I'm assuming the base code's ELF is named `base.elf`.

In an unstripped ELF file, the symbol table is stored in the `.symtab` section. So, to read the symbol table, all you have to do is read that section with `readelf -s base.elf`. The output looks something like this (this is a reduced example and your table will vary):

```
Symbol table '.symtab' contains 5 entries:
   Num:    Value  Size Type    Bind   Vis      Ndx Name
     1: 00000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS uart1.c
     2: 0000832c   100 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 other_function1
     3: 000083c8    48 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT    3 other_function2
     4: 000081dc   336 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 uart1_init
     5: 00009000    12 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    6 uart1
```

All we care about are the global symbols, so you can pipe this output into `grep` and filter for only the global symbols. You can do some more filtering if you'd like to restrict which symbols are copied, but that's up to you.

Once you have that listing of symbols, you can create an assembly file that defines each symbol as an absolute address. Each entry in this assembly file looks something like this:

```
.global uart1_init
.set uart1_init, 0x000081dc
```

Doing this by hand for a lot of symbols would get very tiring very fast, so here's a Python script I came up with to automate converting the `readelf` output into an assembly file:

```py
from os import popen
from sys import argv

symbols = popen(f'readelf -s {argv[1]} | grep GLOBAL | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev').read().splitlines()
addrs = popen(f'readelf -s {argv[1]} | grep GLOBAL | cut -d" " -f6').read().splitlines()

with open(argv[2], 'w') as f:
    for (symbol, addr) in zip(symbols, addrs):
        f.write(f'.global {symbol}\n')
        f.write(f'.set {symbol}, 0x{addr}\n')
```

(The script takes two command line arguments: the input ELF file and the filename of the output assembly source).

Once you get that assembly file with all the symbols you want, you need to assemble it into an object file using the assembler of your choice. If you're using `clang`, then you can use this command (any target that specifies the ELF format should work):

```
clang --target=YOUR_TARGET -c -o symbols.o symbols.S
```

This object file will contain all the symbols you want, and now you can pass it to your linker and the symbols will be resolved to the addresses from the original base ELF.

Note that you'll still need to define all the symbols you use in C to make the compiler happy. This can be done by using `extern` definitions or simply including the header files from the `base.elf`'s source code.

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but I would rather use `awk` and avoid the splitting and zipping altogether: `readelf -s $1 | awk '/GLOBAL/ {print $NF, $2;}'`

Comment: @OlafDietsche That way works too, and it's probably faster too (however, the address needs to be prefixed with `0x` because it's in hex). I just tried to make the script as straightforward as possible in case a future visitor needs to modify it for a different use case and to make it as clear as possible.

Comment: Just prefix with `"0x"` then, e.g. `awk '/GLOBAL/ {print $NF, "0x"$2;}'`

Comment: Btw, it need not be awk, anything else (e.g. perl, ...) might do. My main point was the splitting and subsequent zipping is not necessary. And since you're already using the shell via `popen`, you can leverage what's available.

Comment: Wouldn't using `nm` produce much less noise? It's designed for listing symbol tables.

Comment: @Jens Good point, haven't thought much about alternatives.